# How should I parse using jQuery JSON answer wrapped in Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need parse JSON answer containing this structure

```
{

        "TariffItems": [
            {
                "TariffId": "89",
                "TariffCode": "Y",
                "TariffRusName": "Эконом"
            },
            {
                "TariffId": "67",
                "TariffCode": "C",
                "TariffRusName": "Бизнес"
            },
            {
                "TariffId": "87",
                "TariffCode": "J",
                "TariffRusName": "Премиум"
            }
        ]
    }
```

When I see this in Firebug it's showing that each TariffItems wraped in object and this mean that following jquery cannot get values. How should I change this?

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/Home/GetTariffs",
            type: "post",
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                $.each(result, function () {
                    $("#tariffs").append($("<button class='btn btn-default tariff'/>").val(this.TariffId).text(this.TarifNameRus));
                    $("div#tariffs.btn-group button.btn.btn-default").first().addClass("active");
                });
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                alert(err.Message);
            }
        });
```

Comment: JSON.parse(object) ? Or specify the `dataType` attribute in your ajax parameter with the value of `json`.

Comment: have you tried `$.each(result.TariffItems, function () {`

Comment: @Michael It should be valid JSON before you could do that.

Comment: He didnt supply the JSON string, only the resulting object. I'm going to assume he is working with an object.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets you, re right, that's what I need, together with specifying dataType.

Comment: Please add your comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the ajax code to the following:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/Home/GetTariffs",
        type: "post",
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            $.each(result.TariffItems, function () { // <---------
                $("#tariffs").append($("<button class='btn btn-default tariff'/>").val(this.TariffId).text(this.TarifNameRus));
                $("div#tariffs.btn-group button.btn.btn-default").first().addClass("active");
            });
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            alert(err.Message);
        }
    });
```

You are recieving an Object. the items you want to loop through are part of that object.
Therefore you have to use the object item to be passed to the loop code of jQuery.

In this case result.TariffItems

Comment: @Micheal Dibbets, It should be `this.TariffRusName` instead of `this.TarifNameRus` as per the JSON provided by OP.

Comment: No it should not. The object name is TariffItems what needs to be supplied to the jQuery.each() function. The TariffItems is what contains all the sub items that OP wants to loop through.  And i simply copied his code and changed the essential line.

Comment: Agreed, but the attribute `TarifNameRus` does not exist in the JSON OP provided. I was referring to the first statement within the `each` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fzb6ou3x/). It should be:

```
$.each(result.TariffItems, function () {
                    $("#tariffs").append($("<button class='btn btn-default tariff'/>").val(this.TariffId).text(this.TariffRusName));
                    $("div#tariffs.btn-group button.btn.btn-default").first().addClass("active");
                });
```

Comment: Then what is the situation?